# Writing a separate sheet in excel and not overwrite the previous result sheet

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making an auto-testing tool using selenium. what it does is that it takes the number of times the tests run according to the user input and makes a report on an excel file on the number of tests ran, passed tests, and failed tests. so I was asked to also have the feature for record maintaining and I decided to add the name of the sheet to the current date and time run. what I want is that whenever it runs again, it should make a new sheet with that particular date time and not overwrite the previous sheet. How can I do that? any suggestions, please?[This is the image of my code. it takes a dictionary to match the option selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWfQA.png)

```
now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S")
workbook  = xlsxwriter.Workbook('../Report/FinalResultGUI.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(str(dt_string))
worksheet.write(0,0,"Name")
worksheet.write(0,1,"Test Ran")
worksheet.write(0,2,"Pass")
worksheet.write(0,3,"Failed")
worksheet.write(0,4,"Pass Percentage%")
worksheet.write(0,5,"Fail Percentage%")
worksheet.write(0,6,"Error Message")
```

This is the code. noow whenever the test will run, they will have a name, the number of tests ran, passed, failed passed percentage, and failed percentage. Now I'm saving it in a sheet with the current date and time. I want if I run it some other time, it should not over right the previous sheet, it should create a new sheet with that date and time.

```
for i in range(len(test_keys)):
                res = myDict[test_keys[i]](noOfTimesCustom,targetIP, spareIP)

                worksheet.write(row, 0, res[0])
                worksheet.write(row, 1, res[1])
                worksheet.write(row, 2, res[2])
                worksheet.write(row, 3, res[3])
                worksheet.write(row, 4, res[4])
                worksheet.write(row, 5, res[5])


                row+=1

            workbook.close()
```

This is the for loop that takes the return on the testcases and writes it onto the excel file.

Comment: workbook.add_worksheet is not working for you?

Comment: In general, please avoid posting images of code and instead post the actual code snippet in the question.

Comment: i apologize. its my first time @lee-m

Comment: @ManibhaJain it is. but i want it to make another sheet and not over write the sheet through then loop that is shown above in the code snippet.

Comment: There is a load_workbook  option in  openpyxl  python that you can use ,and then add a new sheet to it , write to that sheet and save the workbook.

Comment: @ManibhaJain can you give a snippit? I'll appreciate that a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet.

```
import openpyxl
ref_workbook= openpyxl.load_workbook('myfile.xlsx')
ref_workbook.create_sheet('new_sheet')
#do your work and then use the following line to save.
ref_workbook.save('myfile.xlsx')
```